# Entity framework execution

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am new to the entity framework and wondered, when the data is actually taken from the database. If I e.g. does:

```
from order in orderQuery where order select car;
```

is the data then selected from the database, or is it first when I manipulate it like the code below?

```
(from order in orderQuery where order select car).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ queries have a property called delayed execution.  This separates out the building and execution of a query into 2 distinct parts.  The first example you gave only defines a query and hence won't cause any execution.  The second however will force the query to run to completion

Answer (score 1):

The entity framework works in lazy-load fashion, the databse is queried only when the data is actually needed.

So the query will only be executed on your second example.